# why index of json object is inconsistent?

Tags: json, indexing, arrays

fisrt JSON

```
{value:[{"sk_service":"1","hour":"0","sum(transaction)":"1636"}]}
```

second JSON

```
{value:[{"sk_service":"1","month":"04","sum(transaction)":"19572"}]}
```

then i do this to know the attribute from my json

```
String a= JSONArray.getJSONObject(0).names().getString(0); //0
String b= JSONArray.getJSONObject(0).names().getString(1); //1
```

results :

first json

```
a = sum(transaction) //index 0.
b = hour         //index 1.
```

second json

```
a = month       //index 0.
b = sum(transaction)    //index 1.
```

Why are the results are inconsistent between first and second json?

Comment: I don't know about JSONArray, but properties of objects are not ordered in JSON, if that's your question.

Comment: Can you fix your sample JSON - fisrt and second have the same structure - if they look the same and you're getting different results then can you post the code you're using to parse it please.

Comment: Both of your JSON examples aren't valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

JSON : JavaScript Object Notation - you treat it as an object and you can access properties explicitly:

This should do the trick:

```
var data = new Array();

for(var index = 0; index < JSONArray.length; index++){
    data.push(eval("(" + JSONArray.getJSONObject(index) + ")"));
}
```

you now have an array that will let you retrieve data explicitly:

```
data[0].value["sk_service"] will give you "1"
data[1].value["month"] will give you "04"
data[0].value["sum(transaction)"] will give you "1636"
```

I'd suggest you re-factor your JSON:

second JSON

```
{value:[{"sk_service":"1","period":"month","duration":"4","transactionSum":"19572"}]}
```

introducing the period and duration properties will simplify your code later
renaming `sum(transaction)` to `transactionSum` will avoid confusion later.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your just getting mixed up.

```
String a= JSONArray.getJSONObject(0).names().getString(0); 
String b= JSONArray.getJSONObject(1).names().getString(0);
```

`getJSONObject()` returns the JSON object, and in your code you seem to be using the same JSON object.

`getString()` returns the string matched to that index. Assuming you want the first element in each JSON, wouldn't specify 0 in both cases